# child class as singleton

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton

In python, I want to design two classes :

1. class A which will have a set of methods.
2. class B which will have all the method of A and be a singleton.

I wrote it like this :

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class A:
    def __init__(self, toto):
        self.toto = toto

    def another_method(self):
        ...


class B(A, metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

is it the proper way to define A and B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a possible way, not the only one.

Using a Metaclass makes sense when it will be reused amont a number of classes. Here you could as well use the `__new__` method from A:

```
class A:
    _instances = {}
    def __new__(cls, toto):
        if cls is A:
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            obj._do_init(toto)
        elif cls not in A._instances:
            A._instances[cls] = object.__new__(cls)
            A._instances[cls]._do_init(toto)
        return A._instances[cls]

    # initialization is moved from the special __init__ method to
    # a private one to prevent subsequent "creations" to change the
    # initial value of the singleton
    def _do_init(self, toto):
        self.toto = toto

class B(A):
    pass
```